# infinite matrix with diagonal rectangle close and open

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix, nicematrix

i want to draw this, with rectangle over sucesion  ${\lambda_{i,i-1}}_{i}$.

Rectangle must be close in \lambda_{1,0} and finish open, not close, i know from others examples how do close in begin and finish, but not open and close

Thanks so much

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do it could be using tikz matrix library. That an a couple of lines and you have it.

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage    {amssymb}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\sep{0.3cm}
  \matrix(D)[matrix of nodes,minimum size=1.2cm]
  {
    $|\alpha|+|\beta|=0$          & $\cdots$        & $\lambda_{1,0}$   & $\lambda_{2,0}$
                                  & $\lambda_{3,0}$ & $\cdots$          & $\lambda_{n-1,0}$
                                  & $\lambda_{n,0}$\\
    $|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant1$  & $\cdots$        & $\lambda_{1,1}$   & $\lambda_{2,1}$
                                  & $\lambda_{3,1}$ & $\cdots$          & $\lambda_{n-1,1}$
                                  & $\lambda_{n,1}$\\
    $|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant2$  & $\cdots$        & $\lambda_{1,2}$   & $\lambda_{2,2}$
                                  & $\lambda_{3,2}$ & $\cdots$          & $\lambda_{n-1,2}$
                                  & $\lambda_{n,2}$\\
    $\vdots$                      &                 & $\vdots$          & $\vdots$
                                  & $\vdots$        & $\ddots$          & $\vdots$
                                  & $\vdots$\\
    $|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant n$ & $\cdots$        & $\lambda_{1,n}$   & $\lambda_{2,n}$
                                  & $\lambda_{3,n}$ & $\cdots$          & $\lambda_{n-1,n}$
                                  & $\lambda_{n,n}$\\
  };
  \draw[thick,red] (D-5-7.south) -- (D-1-3.west) -- (D-1-3.north) -- (D-5-7.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: yes, excellent, thanks SO MUCH

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4mm}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}[xdots/shorten=6pt]
|\alpha|+|\beta|=0          & \Cdots        & \lambda_{1,0}   & \lambda_{2,0}
                            & \lambda_{3,0} & \Cdots          & \lambda_{n-1,0}
                            & \lambda_{n,0}\\
|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant1  & \Cdots        & \lambda_{1,1}   & \lambda_{2,1}
                            & \lambda_{3,1} & \Cdots          & \lambda_{n-1,1}
                            & \lambda_{n,1}\\
|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant2  & \Cdots        & \lambda_{1,2}   & \lambda_{2,2}
                            & \lambda_{3,2} & \Cdots          & \lambda_{n-1,2}
                            & \lambda_{n,2}\\
\Vdots                      &               & \Vdots          & \Vdots
                            & \Vdots        &           & \Vdots
                            & \Vdots\\
|\alpha|+|\beta|\leqslant n & \Cdots       & \lambda_{1,n}   & \lambda_{2,n}
                            & \lambda_{3,n} & \Cdots          & \lambda_{n-1,n}
                            & \lambda_{n,n}\\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [thick,red] 
  ([yshift=-3mm]5-7.south) -- ([xshift=-2mm]1-3.west) 
  -- ([xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=4mm]1-3.north) -- (5-7.east) ;
\line{3-5}{5-7}
\end{NiceMatrix}$
\endgroup                                  
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]